# Replace the element of a column (if consecutive value differ by 10 ) by mean of upper and lower value in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe having a column of temperature. In the temperature column in some rows consecutive values are differing with more than 10 and I want to clean my data set. I want to replace that value with mean of upper and lower value.

I have tried some conditional replacement but that is not working...

```
df.loc[df['Temperature1'] > 50, 'Temperature'] = 23
```

I have tried this but this will change all elements above 50 with 23..
but i want to compare two rows and check the difference if it greater than 10 than only i have to replace..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: you can create new columns with shifted values - value from first row goes to second row, from second row to third row, etc. This way you have values from two rows in one row and you can compare them. You have `df['new_column'] = df[...].shift(step)` for this.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**  added example with [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) (see also: [window functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/computation.html#window-functions))

---

You can use [shift()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to put values from upper row and lower row in middle row.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [10,30,20,40,50]})

df['upper_row'] = df['Temperature'].shift()
df['lower_row'] = df['Temperature'].shift(-1)

print(df)
```

Result

```
   Temperature  upper_row  lower_row
0           10        NaN       30.0
1           30       10.0       20.0
2           20       30.0       40.0
3           40       20.0       50.0
4           50       40.0        NaN
```

And then you have three values in one row and you can normally substract them, calculate mean, compare them, etc

```
df['difference'] = (df['Temperature'] - df['upper_row']).abs()
df['mean'] = (df['upper_row'] + df['lower_row'])/2

print(df)
```

Result

```
   Temperature  upper_row  lower_row  difference  mean
0           10        NaN       30.0         NaN   NaN
1           30       10.0       20.0        20.0  15.0
2           20       30.0       40.0        10.0  35.0
3           40       20.0       50.0        20.0  35.0
4           50       40.0        NaN        10.0   NaN
```

And you can replace values in `Temperature`

```
df['Temperature'][ df['difference']>10 ] = df['mean']

print(df)
```

Result

```
   Temperature  upper_row  lower_row  difference  mean
0           10        NaN       30.0         NaN   NaN
1           15       10.0       20.0        20.0  15.0
2           20       30.0       40.0        10.0  35.0
3           35       20.0       50.0        20.0  35.0
4           50       40.0        NaN        10.0   NaN
```

---

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [10,30,20,40,50]})

df['upper_row'] = df['Temperature'].shift()
df['lower_row'] = df['Temperature'].shift(-1)
print(df)

df['difference'] = (df['Temperature'] - df['upper_row']).abs()
df['mean'] = (df['upper_row'] + df['lower_row'])/2
print(df)

df['Temperature'][ df['difference']>10 ] = df['mean']
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use [rolling window](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to work with two or three consecutive rows. See comments in code.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Temperature': [10,30,20,40,50]})

# work with two consecutive rows and result assign to last row
rw2 = df['Temperature'].rolling(2)
df['difference'] = rw2.apply(lambda rows:abs(rows[1] - rows[0]), raw=True)

# work with three consecutive rows and result assign to middle/center row
rw3 = df['Temperature'].rolling(3, center=True)
df['mean'] = rw3.apply(lambda rows:(rows[0] + rows[2])/2, raw=True)

print(df)

df['Temperature'][ df['difference']>10 ] = df['mean']
print(df)
```